# spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure usage

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm little confused on the usages of the below project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This project seems to be needing the properties with the prefix of

```
security.oauth2.client
```

Whereas, the Spring boot's version of Oauth configuration starts with the below prefix

```
spring.security.oauth2.client
```

Further beyond, the oauth2 autoconfigure project seems to be

1. Limited in scope that it supports only 1 client
2. Provides useful bean types like PrincipalExtractor and AuthoritiesExtractor that doesn't seem to be available in the main spring boot oauth project.

Can someone explain to me the main purpose of this autoconfigure project? Is it like a sample or is it some pilot project that is expected to go mainstream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The project `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` is for migration from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.x, see [OAuth2 Autoconfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html5/):

> This project is a port of the Spring Security OAuth support that came with Spring Boot 1.x. Support was removed in favor of Spring Security 5’s first class OAuth support. To ease migration, this project exists as a bridge between the old Spring Security OAuth support and Spring Boot 2.x.